# How to nuke everything in Prisma?

Tags: prisma, prisma-graphql

I am using Prisma 1.9 with Postgres.

How can I reset everything? I have tried `prisma local nuke` but this command will add MySQL container (somehow) and then it throws error that port `4466` is in use...

I have also tried to recreate all docker containers and images, but that didnt help as well.

So, what's the right way? `prisma reset` only deletes the data but I want delete the schema as well.. I want to wipe it all.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks for asking this one. Meet my two favorite commands:-

1. `armaggedon` - remove everything and images
2. `docker-wipe` - remove everything but not images

Keep them in your environment via the respective profile file.

```
removecontainers() {
  docker stop $(docker ps -aq)
  docker rm $(docker ps -aq)
}

armaggedon() {
  removecontainers
  docker network prune -f
  docker rmi -f $(docker images --filter dangling=true -qa)
  docker volume rm $(docker volume ls --filter dangling=true -q)
  docker rmi -f $(docker images -qa)
}

docker-wipe() {
  docker kill $(docker ps -aq)
  docker rm $(docker ps -aq)
}
```

Comment: Can't we now replace the `armaggedon` with combination of `docker kill $(docker ps -aq)` and `docker system prune -af --volumes`?